# Issue with Freeze() , Thaw() function in wxwidgets in linux

Tags: c++, visual-c++, wxwidgets

I did project in window using `wxwidgets` then i am trying to run it linux but i am getting some problem with **freeze&thaw** function.

Will it work with linux? Is there any other option to freeze the window?

Here is mycode:

```
void *UpdateModeltreeThread::Entry()
{
    m_PtrTree->Freeze();

    m_PtrTree->ProcessUpdateModelTree();

    m_PtrTree->Thaw();

    return NULL;
}
```

**Note:** i am running above thing using wxThread

`ProcessUpdateModelTree()` in this function i am adding treeitems to **wxtreelistctrl** there are number of treeitems are there so i am using freeze&thaw,running at back end using thread function **its working in windows but not in linux**

**Issue:In middle of Freeze() & Thaw() its calling paint event , because ot that its crashing in treelistctrl paint event,but this thing is not happing in window**

Comment: Define "some problem". **EDIT:** see here: http://trac.wxwidgets.org/ticket/10748

Comment: Raised 5 years ago? This is why I prefer Qt

Comment: @enhzflep see my updated data

Comment: @srinivas - I see now what you're trying to do, but still have no idea what the problem is you're faced with. I.e - does freeze/thaw do nothing? Do you get flickering of the controls while in the frozen state? Do you get erroneous updating if the window is in the frozen state. As it stands, the problem is less clear to me (& others?) than you might imagine.

Comment: @enhzflep sorry for improper data , u can see my problem now

Comment: @srinivas - no worries mate. Indeed, your update makes the situation much more clear. Better (more complete) questions get better answers. Looks like VZ may have nailed it, thanks to your updated info.

Answer (score 1):

You absolutely *cannot* call GUI methods such as `Freeze()` and `Thaw()` from worker threads, as you seem to be doing here. You must call them or, better, use safer [wxWindowUpdateLocker](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_window_update_locker.html) from the main thread.